# put data from post to socket js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to read modbus register using jsmodbus. From www site using POST send to modbus register and counter.
I want to put variable inp1, inp2 from app.post to .readHoldingRegister(inp1,inp)
How to do that

```
        app.post('/api/v1/tours', (req,res) =>{
        inp1 = req.body.register;
        inp2 = req.body.count;
        console.log(inp1,inp2);
        res.send('Done powrot');
        if(res.headersSent) { 
            
    console.log('res.headersSent');
        }
    });
    
    
    socket.on('connect', function () {
            
      client
      .readHoldingRegisters(inp1, inp2)
        .then(function (resp) {
          out = resp.response._body._values;
          console.log('out',out)
    
          
          app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send(`Hello from server side ${resp.response._body.valuesAsArray}`);
        
    })
          socket.end()
        }).catch(function () {
          console.error(require('util').inspect(arguments, {
            depth: null
          }))
          socket.end()
          
        })
    
            
    })
    
    
    socket.on('error', console.error);
    socket.connect(options);
    console.log(out);
```